# three.js extend a builtin shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to take an existing working scene setup which has some meshes loaded which render perfectly when setting a MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial onto them. It works with the lights, all the uniforms for the lights are magically being setup under the hood, works great. Shadow mapping works great, too.

Now I want to enhance the shader. I want to add some new stuff in the shader. in my situation this is a set of point lights with hardcoded parameters but you can imagine a practical thing to do would be to open up the ability to configure these dynamically using some uniforms. This is just an intermediate step before re-engineering the render pipeline into performing deferred rendering.

When I go to three.js source and look at renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js we see that the shader for MeshLambertMaterial is called `lambert` here and it is constructed mostly out of shader chunks.

What I have done is taken the entire content verbatim and stuck all of this content into my own `ShaderMaterial`, but my mesh now renders all black.

*There is clearly some additional housekeeping that I must do with `ShaderMaterial` to make it start to behave properly with the lights I have set up through three.js, (so that it is like how the builtin materials behave) but I can't figure out what this is.* (I tried RawShaderMaterial but all it did was make a bunch of shader compiler errors about the `#if` variables not being declared)

Comment: at this point my current latest *great idea* is to fork three.js and directly author a new shaderchunk to inject into the main `'lambert'` or `'phong'` shaders and use these builtin materials as I had been using them before. This way I can be assured that all the bookkeeping magic bits stay the same and the downside here would be relating to that part where i have completely broken code modularity. but for my requirements it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Totally not going to help you anymore but here's how I did it for a customized `MeshPhongMaterial`. The basic idea is to create a `ShaderMaterial` that behaves exactly like a `MeshPhongMaterial` as a starting point, and then continue from there.

First, create the material:

```
hot_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.fragmentShader,
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(THREE.ShaderLib.phong.uniforms)
});
```

You can directly modify the shader source strings here before you assign them (my strategy is to find an existing `#include` and replace that), and you can add new uniforms.

The `UniformsUtils.clone` is necessary because the same `uniforms` object is read every time a `MeshPhongMaterial` is instantiated.

Now, for the additional housekeeping.

The thing that does it is the `refreshMaterialUniforms` function. Specifically, these lines from the source code:

```
...
} else if ( material.isMeshPhongMaterial ) {

    refreshUniformsCommon( uniforms, material );
    refreshUniformsPhong( uniforms, material );

}
...
```

You somehow need to make those 2 calls happen (or copy the code into your project, but that's gnarly). Unfortunately that isn't public so you can't call it directly. The easiest way I found is to simply define `isMeshPhongMaterial` to true on your object.

```
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "isMeshPhongMaterial", { value: true, writable: false });
```

(there is no particular reason why I did it with `Object.defineProperty`, you can just set the property to true normally).

At least for the `MeshPhongMaterial`, setting this property does not have any unwanted side effects in the current version of three.js which is I think r151 or something at the time of writing this. It causes the `needsUpdate` mechanism to work, and it will update uniforms appropriately.

Also, the `MeshPhongMaterial` currently does not have any `defines` which would also need to be passed to the shader. Some other materials do, you can see it in their constructors. In such a case, you would probably just need to copy them over to the `ShaderMaterial`'s `defines` property.

Not done yet though. The two functions above read properties from your material object and pass their values to uniforms. You need to make sure that the properties exist in the object. To do that, the easiest thing is to look in the `refreshUniformsCommon` and `refreshUniformsPhong` functions. Examples are `color` or `map` from `refreshUniformsCommon` or `specular` from `refreshUniformsPhong`. You need *at least* these two, otherwise it will explode (because there aren't any null checks there):

```
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "specular", { value: new THREE.Color( 0x111111 ), writable: true });
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "shininess", { value: 30, writable: true });
```

(The values were taken from the default values in the `MeshPhongMaterial` constructor)

Look through the functions and add the properties which you actually need in your program, for example

```
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "map", { value: null, writable: true });
```

Some of these properties might be set to reasonable default values in the `MeshPhongMaterial` constructor, remember that constructor is no longer running and you need to do that yourself. You could also construct a dummy `MeshPhongMaterial` and copy them over.

The following should work as a drop-in replacement for a `MeshPhongMaterial` that only uses a simple texture:

```
hot_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.fragmentShader,
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(THREE.ShaderLib.phong.uniforms)
});

Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "specular", { value: new THREE.Color( 0x111111 ), writable: true });
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "shininess", { value: 30, writable: true });
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "map", { value: null, writable: true });
Object.defineProperty(hot_material, "isMeshPhongMaterial", { value: true, writable: false });
```